# How to handle multi Google Places API request inside loop in NodeJS?

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, promise, nodes, google-places-api

I have a loop that analyse long array of GPS points, then I pick some points according to what I need.
For each GPS point I want to find places around.

How to make sure to get each response separated from others?

Here is the code inside the loop, it works when I have 1 GPS point, but with more it's not:

Loop the GPS path, saved in hash table:

```
for (let indexI = 0; indexI < path_hash.length; indexI++) {
    for (let indexJ = 0; indexJ < path_hash[indexI].length - 2; indexJ++) {
```

...
Prepare the URL request:

```
location = path_hash[indexI][indexJ].data.coords.latitude + "," + path_hash[indexI][indexJ].data.coords.longitude;
var url = "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/nearbysearch/json?" + "key=" + key + "&location=" + location + "&radius=" + radius + "&sensor=" + sensor + "&types=" + types + "&keyword=" + keyword;
```

...
Execute the request:

```
https.get(url, function (response) {
    var body = '';
    response.on('data', function (chunk) {
        body += chunk;
    });

    response.on('end', function () {
        var places = places + JSON.parse(body);
        var locations = places.results;
        console.log(locations);
    });

}).on('error', function (e) {
    console.log("Got error: " + e.message);
})
```

Comment: Do you have different `url`s for each point? (like a list of points). Please share some more context code (such as initiation of places_list and the way your build your `url`)

Comment: @iuliu.net check now. removed places_list it was a try to handle the multi requests.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using your function you can do it this way

```js
// Turn the callback function into a Promise
const fetchUrl = (url) => {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    https.get(url, function (response) {
      var body = '';
      response.on('data', function (chunk) {
        body += chunk;
      });

      response.on('end', function () {
        var places = places + JSON.parse(body);
        var locations = places.results;
        resolve(locations) // locations is returned by the Promise
      });

    }).on('error', function (e) {
      console.log("Got error: " + e.message);
      reject(e); // Something went wrong, reject the Promise
    });
  });
}

// Loop the GPS path, saved in hash table
...

// Prepare the urls
...

const GPSPoints = [
  'url1',
  'url2',
  ...
];

// Fetch the locations for all the GPS points
const promises = GPSPoints.map(point => fetchUrl(point));

// Execute the then section when all the Promises have resolved
// which is when all the locations have been retrieved from google API
Promise.all(promises).then(all_locations => {
  console.log(all_locations[0]); // Contains locations for url1
  console.log(all_locations[1]); // Contains locations for url2
  ...
});
```

Comment: Can you help to understand what from the above code should be out of the loop is any?

Comment: You want me to include the part that generates the urls?

Comment: want to know when to call Promise.all(promises).then..? after the loop is done?

Comment: I've edited my code above to add where the gps path and the urls are built

Comment: About this piece of code `Promise.all(promises).then(callback)`, `promises` is an array of `Promise`. If you're not familiar with the concept, here is a great article by Eric Elliot: [What is a Promise](https://medium.com/javascript-scene/master-the-javascript-interview-what-is-a-promise-27fc71e77261). A `Promise` is an object to handle asynchronous code. It represents a value that may be available now, in the future or never. If you want to execute a piece of code once a Promise produces a value, you use its `then(callback)` function. `callback` will be called when the value is produced

Comment: That's what `Promise.all(promises).then(handleAllLocations)` is doing. The `handleAllLocations` function is executed once all the promises have prodeced their values. In this specific case, the values are the locations for each gps point

Comment: unbelievable. this concept is amazing, I learned the concept from your example, it works as expected. Thank you @Baboo_